# Compiler issues "__builtin_ia32_foo" not declared in scope when importing headers from PCL installed using vcpkg (likely related to Eigen)

Tags: gcc, eigen, vcpkg, pcl

Problem 1) Very new to C++ and compiling in general, being mostly experienced in Python

Problem 2) I have installed Point Cloud Library (PCL) as per PCL's recommendations using `vcpkg` - specifically using `vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows` -  and am trying to follow the procedure to import .pcd files detailed in [this tutorial](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading_pcd.html). I had written some previous code to list .pcd's in a folder, which compiled fine, however, as soon as I include any PCL libraries, I get a number of compile errors (in cLion console) like:

```
====================[ Build | FallingRockDetectionPC | Debug ]==================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\...\Projects\FallingRockDetectionPC\cmake-build-debug --target FallingRockDetectionPC -j 16
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FallingRockDetectionPC.dir/main.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/FallingRockDetectionPC.dir/main.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.3\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DDISABLE_PNG -D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__SSE__ -D__SSSE3__ -isystem C:/.../Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include -isystem C:/.../Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/eigen3 -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/FallingRockDetectionPC.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\FallingRockDetectionPC.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/FallingRockDetectionPC.dir/main.cpp.obj -c C:/.../Projects/FallingRockDetectionPC/main.cpp

In file included from C:/Users/samue/Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ConfigureVectorization.h:349,
                 from .../vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/Eigen/Core:22,
                 from .../vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/pcl/memory.h:48,
                 from .../vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:42,
                 .
                 .
                 .
...\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.2.0\include\pmmintrin.h: In function '__m128 _mm_addsub_ps(__m128, __m128)':
...\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\12.2.0\include\pmmintrin.h:53:19: error: '__builtin_ia32_addsubps' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_subps'?
   53 |   return (__m128) __builtin_ia32_addsubps ((__v4sf)__X, (__v4sf)__Y);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   __builtin_ia32_subps
```

Plus many more relating to various functions prefixed with `__builtins_ia32`. The errors occur regardless of whether I invoke any of the PCL classes, and occur regardless of the library imported, seeming to be issues stemming from the use of the Eigen library in PCL. (I've replaced some elements of paths with ellipses)

I've done a bit of research and see these are related to machine directives or something to do with vectorising/optimising for specific architecture instruction sets, but as to how to fix it, I have no clue. I have tried recompiling PCL specifically using a x64 version of cMake in `vcpkg`, thinking there might be some architecture issues. I changed from cLion's bundled `mingw` to current 'external' versions. I deleted `vcpkg` and folders in their entirety because I had mistakenly installed x86 versions of packages which were being used by default, and reinstalled PCL.

In the interest of completeness, this is my cMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(FallingRockDetectionPC)

find_package(PCL CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(FallingRockDetectionPC main.cpp load_sequential_pc.cpp load_sequential_pc.h)
target_link_libraries(FallingRockDetectionPC PRIVATE ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

As said, I'm very new to C++, and was kinda using a C++ project like this to try and learn a bit. Maybe not the best one to start with. Appreciate any help anyone can provide. Cheers.

Comment: I don't know what is adding `-D__SSE4_2__` etc, but it is guilty. Those flags should not be defined directly, they are defined as a consequence of passing ` -march=...`.

Comment: Cheers @MarcGlisse, I'll try and track down where that gets added :)

Comment: I don't know vcpkg that well, but isn't x64-windows for use with visual studio, not mingw?

Comment: ahhh, OK, that might be an issue then., thanks for your help, I appreciate it